# Exist algorithms without input data?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I would like to know cases that an algorithm runs without any data entry.

Comment: A cake recipe seems to be a good algorithm without any data entry.

Comment: prime numbers generation.

Comment: @styrofoamfly Cake recipe is not an algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course they exist, and they're useful both practically and theoretically.

Any time you write a computer program to solve some specific task that's hard-coded into the program (for example, to compute some value or find solutions to a specific set of equations you're interested in), that's an algorithm with no input.

If you want to prove undecidability of, e.g., the problem of determining whether a Turing machine halts for every input, the first step is to translate a program that uses its input to a program that doesn't use its input and always computes as if it received some specific input. That's another example of an algorithm without an input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to David Richerby's answer which I find very complete I wanted to add a few specific cases (which actually follow his explanations):

1. The computation of some irrationals such as $\pi$ or $e$.
2. The list of prime numbers and other lists (i.e., lists of logarithms and such) which do not require a seed.
3. Equations in general (but clearly not all as many might require boundary conditions), either algebraic or non-linear. This would also include solving some set of mathematical expressions such as differential equations or integrals.

Hope this helps,